# How to parse the words that I want to extract in a shell command?

Tags: linux, shell, parsing

I am a new beginner to the linux command.

I am trying to manage the large data files and I am showing you a one line from them as below.

```
6       129781361       TAR20   DB;DP=95;FS=0.321;GC=39.60;MQ=60.00;SOMATIC;VT=SNP
```

What I want to extract is the words "FS and its value.

So, I want a value 0.321 included in the FS field.

Of course, I am able to extract those value using R language and other programming languages.

However, it is very laborious tasks because I am now on the linux commands.

Therefore, I would like to learn how to extract FS filed and its value.

Could you tell me how to extract 0.321 from FS filed in a efficient way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -F '[ ;,]+' '{print $6}' file
FS=0.321
```

To get just the value part:

```
awk -F '[ ;,]+' 'split($6, a, "="){print a[2]}' file
0.321
```

Or using `grep -oP` (gnu-grep):

```
grep -oP 'FS=\K[\d.]+' file
0.321
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. What is the  function of + character after ']' ?

Comment: `+` is quantifier to match 1 or more of `[ ;,]` characters a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you could use:

```
perl -ne "/FS=([^;]*)/; print $1" input.txt
```

This will extract everything between the "FS=" and the next semicolon or end of line, whichever comes first.